# Java reflection/generics

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
public static <T> T inCache(T obj) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String[] token = validateCookie(); //gives me to strings
        if (token == null)
            return null;
        if (Cache.get(token[0]) != null) {
            if (Cache.get(token[0]).getClass() == Class.forName(token[1])
                    && obj.getClass() == Cache.get(token[0]).getClass()) {
                T test = (T) Cache.get(token[0]);
                return test;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code above is completely wrong.

Basicly I want to do something like this:

- I want to set the class in my function. for example `inCache<User>();`
- check if the object that i get out of my cache has the same class that i have specified before. `(obj.getClass == User.class)`
- If the classes matches , cast the object to the class and return it. `return (User)obj`

I want to use it like this.

```
User user = inCache<User>();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the class signature, why don't you use something like this:

```
public static <T> T inCache(Class<T> clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
  ...
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
User user = inCache(User.class);
```

Generics can't be used the way you described (`User user = inCache<User>();`) due to type erasure at runtime, i.e. the type of `T` is unknown at runtime in that case.

Also note that it might be better to test using `Class#isAssignableFrom(...)` to be able to check for subclasses as well, e.g. `clazz.isAssignableFrom(Cache.get(token[0]).getClass())`. That way you could pass an interface or super class and still get a match if the object is of a subtype.

Comment: +1. To elaborate a bit . . . instead of `T test = (T) ...`, you would then write `T test = clazz.cast(...)`. (See [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast(java.lang.Object)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29).)

Comment: @MaikKlein you're welcome. Generics are one of the trickier parts of Java ;)

Comment: @Thomas: The VM can't check a cast to `T`. It'll "work" in the sense that uncheckable casts are merely a compile warning, not an error, but it's better to use `clazz.cast(...)`, which is not even a compile-warning, because the VM *can* check it.